# Can I use allocation for some nodes and others don't in a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I don't see the reason why it is necessary to use a pointer then use dynamic memory to allocate the structure. Is there anything stopping me from doing this:

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    struct node *next;
  
} node_t ;

int main(){
    
    node_t *head = NULL;
    node_t person2 = {"Alex", 15, NULL};
    head = person2.name;
    return 0;
}
```

**instead of this:**

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    struct node *next;
  
} node_t ;

int main(){

    node_t *head = NULL;

    node_t *person1;
    person1 = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    person1->next = NULL;
    head = person1;
    return 0;
}
```

I understand the place we are allocation memory is different, but in a **practical** way, do these two ways work differently?  The reason for my question is because I only see the pointer to malloc way in every example online.

And can I use both ways together?

Where I either point an entire node to the next node:

```
head = person1;
```

and the next node could be pointing to next node's name, for example:

```
person1->next = person2.name;
```

If I am not mistaken when we are pointing to a dynamic memory address we are pointing to the first data type's byte in this case would be name[0] byte.

Comment: Add a member to your `struct` (e.g.) `int is_allocated;` and set appropriately. When deleting a node only do `free` if this is set

Comment: They differ greatly in terms of [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime).

Comment: Your first example give a warning about incompatible pointers -- you should fix it by using `head = &person2;` instead

Comment: But, if it were me, I would just always do the `malloc` as, overall, this is simpler

Comment: Try created a linked list based on the contents of a file of arbitrary size, then see which way makes more sense.

Comment: @dbush could you clarify? Create a linked list from a file that has, for example, name and age of individuals?

Comment: @ricpateli Yes, but you don't know ahead of time how many.

Comment: Ok thank you, memory in c makes things more tricky, java and python are a lot more straight forward.

Comment: Actually, allocating a "head" node on the stack could be useful if solving some problem with recursion. Each "layer" of the recursion creates & populates its own head node as appropriate, connects what it received from its caller, then the LL is sent off for some kind of processing. Interesting...

Comment: @ricpateli In the other languages, everything is allocated on the heap. In your case, one would use a memory pool, where the allocation takes place in chunks (acquire a large amount of objects once) and an allocation/release of an object would simply set a flag (whether the object is in use or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is knowing how and when to free the memory used by the linked list -- memory allocated with `malloc` must be freed with `free`, while memory allocated on the stack can't be freed with `free` amd will be freed automatically when the containing frame exits.  Worse, passing such a pointer to `free` or trying to use it after the frame has exiting results in undefined behavior, and both cases might appear to work at first and later cause problems.

One possibility is to mark each node with a single bit flag `onHeap` that is set for nodes allocated with malloc and cleared for other nodes.  That way you at least know whether and given node should be passed to `free`.  That still doesn't help with the possibility of dangling pointers from nodes allocated on the stack being freed while still on a list.

Another possibility is to just "normally" allocate nodes on the heap, but in rare cases where you want to allocate and free a node in the same scope, you can do it on the stack.  So you might have code that looks like:

```
void func(struct node *list) {  // list (probably) on the heap
    struct node local;  // a new node we'll prepend
    // init fields of local with some data
    local.next = list;
    func2(&local);   // some other function
}
```

Here the code that calls this "owns" the list being passed in, and might allocate it any way (on the heap with malloc or some other way) and clean it up the same way.  `func` then just owns the single node it is prepending to pass to func2 (which owns nothing on the list, so won't free anything), and `func` frees `local` automatically when it returns.  Using the stack here can be seen as a local optimization of the allocation.

Comment: So If I use it interchangeably the only way of freeing malloc is at the end of the program ?

Comment: Your calls to `free` need to match up to your calls ro `malloc`.  That's what makes mixing memory allocation methods (stack and heap) so hard.

Answer (score 1):

Lifetimes are the issue. If your nodes are automatically declared within `main` you side-step this issue, but as soon as nodes start originating in other functions this crops up.

Let's say we create a `create_node` function which takes an int value and a pointer to the next node and returns a new node.

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *create_node(int value, struct node *next) {
    struct node new_node = {.value=value, .next=next};
    return &new_node;
}
```

This returns a pointer to a local variable. Undefined behaviour ensues.

If we dynamically allocate the memory, the node outlives the scope of the function.

```
struct node *create_node(int value, struct node *next) {
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (!new_node) return NULL;
    
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->next = next;

    return new_node;
}
```

We can now safely write something like:

```
struct node *prepend_value(struct node *list, int value) {
    struct node *new_node = create_node(value, list);

    return new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet I think you mean

```
head = &person2;
```

instead of

```
head = person2.name;
```

Of course you may use local variables as nodes of a list. But in this case if the list needs to store numerous nodes then you will need to declare different numerous local variables that will represent nodes that is inefficient and makes your program very huge an unreadable.